# Cannot add date parameter in Rest request (Rest Sharp)

Tags: c#, restsharp, request-headers

I´m trying to send some JSON information to a server. I add a preserialzed string to the body and place some attributes to the header.

```
            RestClient client = new RestClient(requURI);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(reqPath, method);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            request.AddHeader("Date", getIsoStringFromDate(DateTime.Now));
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", JSonString, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Everything works perfecty except for the date Header that won`t show up. When I change the line to

```
           request.AddHeader("Datexxx", getIsoStringFromDate(DateTime.Now));
```

It will be shown in the header (see network trace)

```
          System.Net Information: 0 : [5620] ConnectStream#61150033 -   Header 
          {
           Datexxx: 2015-03-16 16:19:39
           Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
           User-Agent: RestSharp 104.1.0.0
           Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
           Host: localhost:8080
           Content-Length: 620
           Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
           Connection: Keep-Alive
          }
```

I assume "date" is a predefined or prefilled value by Rest Sharp.

I added a dateFormat definition with

```
          request.DateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
```

But there s still no date header attribute showing up. Also tried the clear all parameters before adding but doesn`t help either.

There has been a github bug concerning this but it is more than 2 years old.. maybe I´m just missing something like a "includeDateInHeader" switch.

I use .Net 3.5 and Rest Sharp 104.1.0.0. or 105.1.0.0. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems some attributes such as **content-type** or **date** cannot be added as parameter but are added internally. To alter the value of "content-type" I had to change the serialzer setting (altough I didn`t use it because I added a json in the body that was serialized before!)

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(requURI);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(reqPath, method);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.Parameters.Clear();             
request.AddHeader("Date", getIsoStringFromDate(DateTime.Now));
            request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

as soon as I did this the header showed up as intended:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [5620] ConnectStream#61150033 -   Header 
{
 Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
 User-Agent: RestSharp 104.1.0.0
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 ...
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't adds Date parameter, did you find out the reason or solution ?